# Passing Recordset Type Error

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, recordset

I am getting a type error when trying to pass a Recordset to a method of one of my classes.
My code looks like this:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.recordset
'do some connection stuff
'create command
rs.Open cmd
dataWriter.write(rs)
```

And the method looks like this:

```
sub write(byRef record as ADODB.recordset)
    range("A1").CopyFromRecordset record
end sub
```

Everything works except the type error I get when trying to pass the recordset to the `write` sub (for example If I call `range("A1").copyfromrecordset rs` in the first block of code it works fine).

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried passing it byVal?

Comment: Gives me the same thing, runtime error 13: Type Mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> dataWriter.write (rs)
> ```

Remove the parentheses. These are forcing `rs` to be *evaluated* and passed `ByVal` **regardless** of what the signature for `write` says: basically you're passing the recordset's default property value (which is its `Fields` property getter, so an `ADODB.Fields` object) into a parameter that expects an `ADODB.Recordset`, hence the *Type Mismatch* error.

```
dataWriter.Write rs
```

Will pass the recordset reference... which should really be passed `ByVal`, since `Write` doesn't need to reassign that reference at all.

```
Sub Write(ByVal record As ADODB.Recordset)
    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset record
End Sub
```

The takeaway is that parentheses *evaluate* an expression - try this in the immediate pane:

```
?TypeName(New ADODB.Recordset)
 Recordset

?TypeName((New ADODB.Recordset))
 Fields
```

---

Note that `Range("A1")` is implicitly referring to the active worksheet, which is sloppy. You should explicitly take a `target` parameter there:

```
Sub Write(ByVal record As ADODB.Recordset, ByVal target As Excel.Worksheet)
    target.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset record
End Sub
```